# Python regex group() works explanation

Tags: python, regex

Could someone please explain why below each print gives different result?  thanks.

```
import re
s = "-h5ello"
m = re.match("-\w(\d\w+)", s)
print ' m.group(): ',(m.group())
print ' m.group(0): ',(m.group(0))
print ' m.group(1): ',(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

`m.group()` and `m.group(0)` should be, and are, identical.

`m.group(1)` only gives you the match from inside the first pair of parentheses.

**EDIT** to clarify what a "matched group" is:

In regular expressions, plain parentheses are called "captures". The reason for this is the fact that they capture submatches into capture groups. Consider this:

```
import re
m = re.match(r'a(b)c(d(e)f)g', 'abcdefg')
print m.group()
# => 'abcdefg'
print m.groups()
# => ('b', 'def', 'e')
```

`m.group(0)`, or equivalently `m.group()`, is the whole match. Parentheses pick out submatches, with first parenthesis pair yielding `m.group(1)`, second `m.group(2)`, and third `m.group(3)`.

In your example, you have parentheses too. They do not include `-\w`, so your `m.group(1)` does not include `-h` part of your string - they only include the submatch for `\d\w+`, which is `5ello`.

Comment: Yes, i see that. I was looking for more global answer. Difference between group() and group(1). Both group() and group(1) should print the same result as I have only one matched string here. Then why group() and group(1) acts differently?

Comment: Geting clear now. One additional question. If group(1) only take into accounts things inside parentheses then why group(1) gives no result for s = "-eh5ello" ?

Comment: Because that is not a match. You wanted a dash, a letter, a digit, and some more letters; but you have a dash, *two* letters, a digit and some more letters.

Answer (score 1):

`m.group()` and `m.group(0)` simply return the whole string if there was a match.
The reason they're identical is that the function is defined with a default value of zero:

```
def group(num=0):
```

As for the matches:
`m.group(1), m.group(2)...` returns the matched groups (in your case - there's only one)

More about matche groups can be found in *[the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)*

Comment: Hello, yes, I can see that, but I cannot see any explanation in python doc.  What is the difference between 'whole string' and 'matched groups'

Comment: You can read [*here*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) look for: `\number` Further, see the update in the answer above.